# Is there anyway to combine prompt with document.write in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a little quiz in JavaScript, but currently it asks the users questions in a prompt window, which in turn captures their answers. I would like the quiz to display questions on a page, and have the users enter their answers on the same page. I'm not sure how to implement this or even where to begin. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: HTML was made [for this type of problems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Comment: Don't use `prompt()` or `document.write()`. Use input elements, buttons, and DOM modification methods like (to start simple) `.innerHTML`.